# Where does the ScrollViewer come from?

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

There is a simple Page (MainPage.xaml)

```xml
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Button x:Name="Button" Content="Button"/>
</Page>
```

and the Page class is as follow

```cpp
struct MainPage : PageT<MainPage>
{
  inline static uint32_t SEQ = 0;
  void Dump(FrameworkElement fwk)
  {
    printf("= %ws\n",get_class_name(fwk).data());
    if(fwk.Parent())
      Dump(fwk.Parent().as<FrameworkElement>());
  }  
  MainPage()
  {
    try
    {
      Application::LoadComponent(*this,Uri(L"ms-appx:///MainPage.xaml"));      
      FindName(L"Button").as<UIElement>().LosingFocus([&](IInspectable sender, LosingFocusEventArgs const& args){
        printf("%03d Button::LosingFocus\n",SEQ++);
        if (args.NewFocusedElement())
        {
          printf("  %ws %ws\n",
            get_class_name(args.OldFocusedElement()).data(),
            get_class_name(args.NewFocusedElement()).data());
          Dump(args.NewFocusedElement().as<FrameworkElement>());
        }
        else if (args.OldFocusedElement())
          printf("  %ws null\n",
            get_class_name(args.OldFocusedElement()).data());
        else
          printf("  null null\n");
      });
    }
    catch(hresult_error e)
    {
      printf("MainPage 0x%x %ws\n",int32_t(e.code()),e.message().data());
    }
  }
  hstring GetRuntimeClassName() const override
  {
    return L"MainPage";
  }
};
```

When the Button is losing focus the output is as follow

```
000 Button::LosingFocus
  Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer
= Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ScrollViewer
```

It seems UWP is trying to refocus to a ScrollViewer which I find nowhere for it. Is it a synthesized one? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where does the ScrollViewer come from?

During the testing, it only occurs there is on other control could be focused, and the `ScrollViewer` should be the visual container that use to render control, And you could find the Button with visual tree helper from the `ScrollViewer`. And you could use the following code to find the root parent of `Button` is ScrollViewer.

```
public static DependencyObject FindParent(DependencyObject dp)
{
    DependencyObject parent = null;
    DependencyObject currParent;
    currParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dp);

    do
    {
        parent = currParent;
        // find the next parent
        currParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(currParent);

    } while (currParent != null);

    return (parent);
}
```

Usage

```
var parent = FindParent(button);
```